# Multiplication problem for formal power series given in a pseudobasis

Tags: formal-power-series, cauchy-product

My question is about the topological algebra $F$ of [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, which is the set of formal power series with multiplication given by the Cauchy product.

The index of a formal power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is the smallest natural number $t$ such that $a_t \not= 0$. The topology on $F$ is given by the metric $d(A, B) = 2^{-k}$, where $k$ is the index of $A-B$.

It is my understanding that any sequence $\{L_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of formal power series such that the index of $L_n$ equals $n$ forms a pseudobasis of $F$ in the sense that if $A \in F$ then there exists a unique sequence of $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n L_n$ converges to A.

Now let $L_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty l_{n,k} x^k$, where $x$ is the formal variable, so that $l_{n,k}$ is an infinite triangular array. My question is whether there is a formula in terms of $l_{n,k}$ for the array $\theta_{i,j}$ defined by $
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=j}^\infty \theta_{i,j} L_i = (\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty l_{n,k} x^k)(\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty \sum_{r=\nu}^\infty l_{\nu,r} x^r).$

I have tried just working it out order by order in $x$ but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Comment: Please define *index*.

Comment: @JohnBentin edited, thanks.

Comment: Why would the product yield a double sum? It should be $\sum_{i=n+\nu}^{\infty}\theta_iL_i.$ But finding the formula for general $L_i$ is not going to be easy.

Comment: I would note that each $L_n(x)$ can be written $x^nf_n(x)$ where $f_n(x)\in F$ is invertible. But with general $f_n,$ it is going to be hard to get a general formula.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in regards to your first comment, yes I agree but I would like to find $\theta_{i,j}$ in that form.

Comment: @the_sandcastler but $\theta_{ij}$ won't be unique. My example will always give $\theta_{ij}=0$ when $i\neq j.$

Comment: Your definition of *index* makes no sense unless $a_0=0$, in which case your index is $0$.

Comment: @JohnBentin thanks again, edited.

Comment: Your definition still doesn't cover the case $a_n=0\;(n\in\Bbb N)$. For that case, you might assign $k=\infty$, with the convention that $2^{-\infty}:=0$.